# Change tint color of UIButton based on background image

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimageview

I have an `UIImageView` with a close button having white tint color, but if the background image is of white color UIbutton is not visible. I need to change `UIButton` color programatically based on the background image's color.

[image]

Is there any way we can change the color of `UIButton` based on the image placed in `UIImageView`?

Comment: I think what you are trying to achieve is really complex and probably not feasible, as the background can be of thousands of colors. You can simply add a blackish gradient at the top left corner of imageview, or you can add a gray background color to your button to make it more visible and make the corners rounded to make it look good.

Comment: @MeeranTariq Thank you I will try

Answer (score 0):

here is the extension to set the background color for UIButton according to his sate selected, normal or highlighted

```
extension UIButton {

    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControl.State) {
        self.clipsToBounds = true  // add this to maintain corner radius
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
            context.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
            let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: forState)
        }
    }

}
```

and you can also set the button tint color Like

```
loginButton.tintColor = .red
```